# Qlikview authentication request blocked because it's a cross-origin request

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've developed an website in Asp.net using VB. One of the requirements was for a `qlikview` to be displayed.

It's under a type of report hub, where I've got a list on the side of the page where the user can select a report and the rest of the page is an `iframe`. When the user selects a report, a `javascript` function is fired which sets the address of one of the reports into the `iframe`. The reports are all on their own page so I'm basically calling the page from the same domain and showing it in the `iframe`, no issue here. The problem comes when I've got to display the `Qlikview` which is hosted on another server.

This throws an error in the inspector but it still displays fine, it works like this on Chrome, Edge, Explorer and Firefox. 
The issue comes with Safari, it blocks the authentication request because it is a cross-origin request.

[I've tried the answer from this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame) I've tried changing the domain name as listed [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)
I've tried allowing cross origin access as listed [here,](https://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html) but it didn't help.

I'm still very new to this, so i apologize if this is a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here - Maybe this can help you
[Using cors with all modern browsers](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/using-cors-with-all-modern-browsers)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. That webpage led me to enable-cors.org, I found a way to enable cors on the server and the aps project, but neither helped.

Answer (score 0):

If it is working ok on Chrome and Firefox it is set ok on server. Qlikview officially support IE and Chrome. Safari have some issue with headers.

If you host your add-on (what is in iframe for Qlikview) on S3 for example for Safari you need to allow origin header, probably on different hostings something similar:

```
 <AllowedHeader>origin</AllowedHeader>
```

Workaround is also that on Qlikview server it can use IIS for displaying Qlikview access point. If you want you can just go to IIS settings on Qlikview server and just set folder where you deploy your add-on pages so this way it can be configured that both will be served from the same domain (your add-on and qlikview access point). There is also Qlikview server configuration without IIS with Qlikview Web Server which will not allow to deploy another site.

Comment: I still get the Error in the dev console, but the Authentication pop up isn't blocked on other browsers so I'm able to insert the username / password and see the Qlikview, but in safari it blocks this Authentication pop up.

Comment: "Authentication pop up" from qlikview or from add-on/iframe?

Comment: from the qlikview in the iframe

Comment: only one thing for Safari which comes to my mind is unblock popups (Ctrl+Shift+K or go through gear options and unselect block pop-ups) or just clear all cookies from Safari